In a tournament, there are twelve players $S_1,S_2,....,S_{12}$ and divided into six pairs at random
In a tournament, there are twelve players $S_1,S_2,....,S_{12}$ and divided into six pairs at random. From each game a winner is decided on the basis of a game played between the two players of the pair. Assuming all the players are of equal strength, then
(i) Probability that $S_{2}$ is among the loosers is
(ii) Probability that exactly one of $S_3$ and $S_{4}$ is among the loosers is
(iii) Probability that both $S_{2}$ and $S_{4}$ are among the winners is
(iv) Probability that $S_{4}$ and $S_{5}$ not playing against each other is
I got answer for the questions (i), (ii), (iii) as $\dfrac{1}{2}$, $\dfrac{6}{11}$ and $\dfrac{5}{22}$
I am not able to solve part (iv) of this question. Please Help me find solution of part (iv)

Note on spelling - you mean "losers", not "loosers". But consider how many opponents $S_4$ could have.

How did you get the answers for (ii) and (iii) without knowing the probability that $S_2$ and $S_4$ are playing each other?

A simpler approach is to note that $S_4$ has one opponent out of $11$.  The chance it is not $S_5$ is then $1-\frac 1{11}=\frac {10}{11}$

There are $11\times 9\times 7\times 5\times 3$ ways to split the players into pairs. (Take player $S_1$, there are $11$ ways to choose a pair for him, now take any free player, there are $9$ ways to choose a pair for him, and so on.)
There are $9\times 7\times 5\times 3$ ways to do that if $S_4$ and $S_5$ are in one pair.
So the probability is $$1- \frac{9\times 7\times 5\times 3}{11\times 9\times 7\times 5\times 3}=1-\frac1{11}= \frac{10}{11}.$$

@RossMillikan I see. I misinterpreted what (ii) is about.
